# Adding a characters in a pattern

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file like this.

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5 etc.
```

I would like to to add two characters 'a' and 'b' at the end of each line alternatively.The output should look like:

```
Line1/a
Line2/b 
Line3/a 
Line4/b ..
```

The idea I have is that

```
if (Linenumber %2 == 0) {
  add a;
}
else 
{
  add b
}
```

I am trying to implement this using either `awk` or `bash`. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You have your idea the other way around. It should be add `a` when `linenumber % 2 == 1` and not `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ printf "%s/%s\n", $0, ((NR % 2) == 1) ? "a" : "b" }' text.file
```

Or even:

```
awk 'BEGIN { s[1] = "a"; s[0] = "b" }
           { printf $0 "/" a[NR % 2]}' text.file
```

Comment: Missing `/` in second version.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0 {print $0"/a"} NR % 2 == 1 {print $0"/b"}' afile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print $0"/"(NR%2?"a":"b")}' file
Line1/a
Line2/b
Line3/a
Line4/b
Line5/a
```

Answer (score 0):

A funny pure Bash possibility:

```
mapfile -t ary < file
((n=${#ary[@]}))
printf '%s/a\n%s/b\n' "${ary[@]::(n/2)*2}"
((n%2)) && printf '%s/a\n' "${ary[@]: -1}"
```

This will slurp the whole file in memory and then use `printf` to print the content, while appending `/a` or `/b` at the end of each line. The case of an odd number of lines is handled properly.